# How to pretty print to a variable instead of STDOUT?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to use Ruby's `pp` to "print" to a variable instead of to STDOUT. How is that done?

Comment: Anything is possible given enough time, money and resources.  If you tell us what you're trying to accomplish, perhaps we can save you some time and effort by offering the best solution.

Comment: Is Google down or something?

Comment: That was kinda snarky, but fair enough. Updated the question.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/15284694/32453

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
require 'pp'
result = PP.pp(some_variable, "")
```